# string similarity check in google sheets using google apps script (range spelling updater)

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, data-cleaning

**I'm writing a program that:**

- iterates over a range
- compares each current cell against string (string is correctly spelled word. this assumes each new word is spelled correctly)
- updates the current cell to match the string if it is similar (>= set percentage)

**important note:** This is meant to iterate over a range in one column, and I currently have no need to iterate over multiple columns.

The program is currently in working condition, but it has a lot of trouble with long strings, and I cant figure out why. I wanted to see if someone can point me in the right direction.

**Purpose of this program:**

I am currently stuck working with dirty data from an OCR import that was undesirable.

a lot of my duplicate values are misspelled (and not in a spellcheck-friendly way)

**for example:**

- testing
- t3st1ng
- t3 st 1 g
- tes5fng
- te5f1n@
- bananas
- 3abanas
- benAnes
- 8n4anans

**is corrected as:**

- testing
- testing
- testing
- testing
- testing
- bananas
- bananas
- bananas
- bananas

I am making all of these values equal to the first value. 
When it gets to bananas, it uses bananas as the new first value.
I hope that makes sense.

The program executes perfectly using this first example

BUT

**The problem is when I have strings like this:**

- this is a test of the emergency broadcast radio system
- this is a test oof the emer gency broadcast r@io  system
- th1s is a test of the emerg3ncy broadcast radio  system
- the emergency broadcast radio system is now testing
- the emergency br0adcast radio sy stem is now t3sting
- the emergency broadc[st r adio sysfm is now testing
- please do not be alarmed as this is only a test
- please do not be alarmed as t his is only 2 test
- plea se do not be @larm3d as t7is is only a best
- and now back to your regularly scheduled programming
- and now 8ack to your re gularly scheduled program ming
- and  now 8ack  to your re@flarly scheduled pr ogramming

**is corrected as:**

- this is a test of the emergency broadcast radio system
- this is a test of the emergency broadcast radio system
- this is a test of the emergency broadcast radio system
- this is a test of the emergency broadcast radio system
- this is a test of the emergency broadcast radio system
- this is a test of the emergency broadcast radio system
- this is a test of the emergency broadcast radio system
- this is a test of the emergency broadcast radio system
- this is a test of the emergency broadcast radio system
- this is a test of the emergency broadcast radio system
- this is a test of the emergency broadcast radio system
- this is a test of the emergency broadcast radio system

Here is my program.

```
function repairDuplicates() {
  try {

    // necessities
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var as = ss.getActiveSheet();


    var sr = as.getDataRange();   // entire sheet range
    var ar = as.getActiveRange(); // active range

    var srv = sr.getValues(); // values of entire sheet
    var arv = ar.getValues(); // values of active range

    function minify(x){ // take a string. trim, remove all white space, convert to array, capitalize, remove special characters
      var txt = x.trim();
      txt = txt.replace(/ /g, '');
      var arr = txt.split('');
      arr = arr.map(function(a){return a.toUpperCase()});
      var std = arr.sort();
      var reg = new RegExp(/\W{1}/);
      for (var z = 0; z < std.length; z++){
        if (reg.exec(std[z]) != null){
          std.splice(z,1);
        }
      }
      return std;
    }


    function compareLength(x,y){ //take two arrays and compare length. if the length is different, then make it the same length by adding "x" n number of times. this will modify the arrays
      var xl = x.length;
      var yl = y.length;
      if (xl < yl){
        for (xl; xl < yl; xl++){
          x.push("x");
        }
      }
      else if (yl < xl){
        for (yl; yl < xl; yl++){
          y.push("x");
        }
      }
    }

    function compareData(x,y){ //take two arrays and compare data. if the arrays match, return "match". else if the arrays are more than (50)% similar, return "pass". else, return "fail"
      var z = [];
      var result;
      if (x.toString() == y.toString()){
        result = "match";
      }
      else if (x.toString() != y.toString()){
        var z = y.filter(function (word) {
          return x.indexOf(word) != -1;
        });

        //ui.alert(x);
        //ui.alert(x.length);
        //ui.alert(z);
        //ui.alert(z.length);

        var score = z.length/x.length;

        if(score > 0.5){
          result = "pass";
        }
        else{
          result = "fail";
        }
      }
      return result;
    }

//    function checkFirst(r, c, x, y){ // deprecated. no need to verify first cell
//      if(r == 0 && c == 0){
//        x = y;
//      }
//      return x;
//    }


    function iterate(range, values, text){ // takes a data range, the values of the range, and a string. 
                                           // iterates over range data (row by row, and cell by cell in each row).
                                           // each current cell is checked and compared against the string.
                                           // if the current cell passes the similarity check (compareData), then make the current cell equal to the previous cell
                                           // if the current cell fails the similarity check, then do not change the value of the cell, but make the string(text) equal to the current cell
      for (var r = 0; r < values.length; r++) {
        var row = values[r];
        for (var c = 0; c < row.length; c++) {
          var cell = row[c];
          //ui.alert("using: " + text);
          //ui.alert(cell);
          var arr = minify(cell);
          var minTxt = minify(text);
          compareLength(minTxt, arr);
          var t = compareData(minTxt, arr);
          //ui.alert(cell + ": " + t)
          if (t == "pass"){
            values[r][c] = text;
          }
          else if (t == "fail"){
            ui.alert("\"" + text + "\"" + "\n \n" +"does not match" + "\n \n" + "\"" + cell + "\"" +  " on row number " + (r + 2) + "..." + "\n \n" + "\"" + cell + "\"" + " is the new comparison string");
            text = cell;
          }
        }
      }
      range.setValues(values);
    }



    // main loop
    var txt = ar.getValue();
    //ui.alert(txt);
    iterate(ar, arv, txt);


  }
  catch (err) {
    ui.alert(err);
  }
}
```

and here is [a link to the sheet that I am testing on](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12w4rGArGi1I1wlpm5yJJtT5AAlMM4LcZC31_DpP6jZQ/edit?usp=sharing).

**Things I have tried:**

- adjusting the percentage of similarity rate. tweaking it between 70-90% yields better results.. but still not completely accurate.
- turning off compareLength. got the same exact result suprisingly

**Theories:**

- this would definitely work better if I were able to use "includes" as opposed to "indexOf", but as far as I know, google apps script does not support ES6

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It looks like your similarity is entirely based on string length, and not the contents of the strings being similar. Even though `abcdefghi` and `ihgfedcba` contain exactly the same characters and have the same length, they are in no means different just by a bad OCR import.

Comment: @tehhowch that is not entirely true. In the compareData function, I am checking for similar values and then returning an array of values that did not match.       

else if (x.toString() != y.toString()){
        var z = y.filter(function (word) {
          return x.indexOf(word) != -1;
        });

in this case, i should be getting back an accurate amount of non matching characters. I then use that amount and divide it by how many characters are in the desired string. Does that make sense?

Comment: Id also like to add that if it were possible to use the array method "includes" instead of using the object/array method "indexOf", then this would be resolved!

Comment: @Nikki `if it were possible to use the array method "includes" instead of using the object/array method "indexOf"` Why?

Comment: @I'-'I because "includes" would ignore extra and irrelevant charaters. for example.. if my string is "testing" and my cell is "testtting123"... it would ignore the two additional "t"s and the "123" and I would get a match. In that case, I could just check and see how many matching characters there are and forget about testing against the non matching ones. this would give me a more accurate similarity percentage.

Comment: @Nikki I don't think it'll ignore the two `t`s.. though it'll ignore the `123`.  There's also a [``polyfill``](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Polyfill) for `includes`.

Comment: @I'-'I var x = ['t','e','s','t','i','n','g'];
var y = ['t','e','s','t','t','t','i','n','g','1','2','3'];
var result;

var z = x.filter((word) => y.includes(word));

console.log(z);

\n

this returns an array ["t", "e", "s", "t", "i", "n", "g"]

so... maybe if I use that polyfill I will have my solution. thanks! will update if/when I get it resolved

Comment: only problem is that I cant figure out how to insert that polyfill into my lambda =(